# Name for a specific relationship between two functions

Tags: functions, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that we have two functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$$ f(x, g(x, y)) = y \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$

They're not exactly inverses, but is there a specific name for the relationship between $f$ and $g$? If not, references to similar relationships would be much appreciated.

Comment: function composition ...

Comment: If you wanna jump some semantic hoops you can say they are invertible in their second argument. Or if you fix an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ beforehand, then they are inverse in $y$. I don't think this is an established concept in a sense that it has a distinct name